# Node JS event not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make an event fire in my node JS code but cannot work out why it isn't.

I have a module as follows:

```
var zookeeper = require('node-zookeeper-client'),
    events = require('events'),
    util = require('util');
var client;

var KafkaZookeeperMonitor = function(){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);  
}

util.inherits(KafkaZookeeperMonitor, events.EventEmitter);

KafkaZookeeperMonitor.prototype.connectToZk = function(zookeepers){
    client = zookeeper.createClient(zookeepers);
    client.connect();

    client.once('connected', function () {
        console.log('Connected to ZooKeeper');
        this.emit('connected');
    });
}

module.exports = KafkaZookeeperMonitor;
```

and I call this from my index.js file as follows:

```
var KafkaZookeeperMonitor = require('./kafkaZookeeperMonitor'),
    kafkaStatus = new KafkaZookeeperMonitor(),
    brokerPath = '/brokers/ids';

kafkaStatus.connectToZk('192.168.50.252:2181');

kafkaStatus.once('connected', function(){
    console.log('watcher connected to Zookeeper');
})
```

When I run the code I get the log message

> 'Connected to Zookeeper'

but the `this.emit('connected');` does not seem to fire.

I've looked around on the web and I think I'm setting up my event emitter correctly.  Can anybody help me out where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: for your reference : http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/

Comment: I would block out that IP if I were you. :)

Comment: Its only a local VM :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of the callback function is not the `KafkaZookeeperMonitorz` Object so `this` is not really the Object instance.

This should work:

```
KafkaZookeeperMonitor.prototype.connectToZk = function(zookeepers){
  var self = this;
  client = zookeeper.createClient(zookeepers);
  client.connect();

  client.once('connected', function () {
      console.log('Connected to ZooKeeper');
      self.emit('connected');
  });
}
```

The reason it's not throwing an error may be because the `client` is also extending `EventEmitter`

Comment: You helped him too much! Teach all the coders the scope!

Comment: @Xogle Yeah... well, it's up to the OP to research and understand why instead of **programming by coincidence**

Comment: @Maroshii agreed, hopefully OP does because if they continue in the pattern they are going, they will run into many scope issues. :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe 'this' is what you think it is...

```
this.emit('connected');
```

Debug and make sure your 'this' is what you are looking for...

http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/